# Making string of 2-d array in scala

Tags: scala

So I have the following in Scala:

```
scala> val example = "hello \tmy \nname \tis \nmaria \tlee".split("\n").map(_.split("\\s+"))
example: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(hello, my), Array(name, is), Array(maria, lee))
```

I want to take each 1-d array and make it into a string, and make an array of these strings (strings should be comma separated). How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> example.map(_.mkString)
res0: Array[String] = Array(hellomy, nameis, marialee)
```

To make the strings comma separated:

```
scala> example.map(_.mkString(","))
res0: Array[String] = Array(hello,my, name,is, maria,lee)
```

Comment: what if I want to comma separate the strings?

Comment: `mkString` takes a separator parameter so call `mkString` with `","`. Calling it with no parameter uses a default value which is apparently an empty string.